# How to create the column smartly?

Tags: excel

In bash:

```
for i in `seq 1 9`; do echo ${i}"th"; done
1th
2th
3th
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
9th
```

I want to create a column containing `1th.....9th` in excel.
Here is what i do in excel.
1.to create column a containing from 1 till 10.

Enter 1 in a cell, and enter 2 in a cell beside the first cell.
Select both the cells, and drag the fill handle Description: Selected cell with fill handle across the range till 10.

2.=CONCATENATE(A2,"th") for B2 ,and drag in b column till 10.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoA2y.png)

Is there some function can create a sequence number?
No need to create column a if there is a function can called.
More smart way to create column b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW` function

```
=ROW() & "th"
```

[image]